# Threebox on Mapbox: 3D Model Disappears with Low Camera Pitch

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, threebox

I loaded a 3D model using Threebox on Mapbox with the projection set to 'globe.' However, I'm facing an issue where the 3D model disappears when the camera pitch is close to 0. Is there a solution to this problem?

I tried loading a 3D model using Threebox on Mapbox with the projection set to 'globe.' However, I encountered an issue where the 3D model disappears when the camera pitch is close to 0. I was expecting the 3D model to remain visible even at low camera pitch angles.